# Regex: check if string corresponding Word numbering list style

Tags: regex

I'm looking for regex-way to find if a string matches any of this pattern:

2.

1.2

3.4.5

These numbers are taken from the numbering list of Word.

Comment: it could be this `^\d(?:\.(?!\.)|\d)*$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to match what is above, use `^((\d\.)+\d|(\d\.))$`. ([Link to regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/o1J4nA/3)).

This will either match that first kind of pattern (with a digit and then a period) or the other two, which have a digit followed by a period more than 1 time, and another digit at the end.

---

If you also want to match patterns like `3.4.`, i.e., strings that may or may not end in a period, you can use `^(\d\.)+\d?$` ([Link](https://regex101.com/r/o1J4nA/4))

This matches patterns that have a digit followed by a period one or more times, and then maybe a digit after that.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I need an exact matching. So, if the string is "1.2text" then it shouldn't be matched. I tried ^(\d\.)+\d|(\d\.)$ but it didn't help.

Comment: @GrigoryZhadko Look at my answer now. What you did was almost correct, but you forget the open parens after `^` and close parens before `$`. It should be `^((\d\.)+\d|(\d\.))$` instead. Notice that the `|` would be applied incorrectly otherwise

Comment: It works. I also forgot to mentions two more requirements:

1. It can be not only digits but numbers as well

2. There is no limit to these numbers.

So the string like this should be also valid:
2222.11111.4444.55555.3.2.1


However, based on your answer I could figure out how to reach this goal:

^(((\d+)(\.))|((((\d+)(\.))+)(\d+)))$